# deferred email sending in django?

Tags: django, django-mailer

Is there an easy way to be able to send an email at a later time, say Aug 1, 2012 6 pm? I have tried to read some documentation on django-mailer, but I could not get to an answer.

I am starting out in web development so may not be able to hack the existing application of django-mailer to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) can fit your need.

First set up a celery task:

```
@task
def sendmail():
    pass
```

Send a mail later, an example from the [doc](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
sendmail.apply_async(args=[], eta=tomorrow)
```